# why does modular division operation works different incase of negative numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

when Iam performing modular division on negative numbers,I found that it is not same as in case of positive numbers

I've tried

```
>>> -123%10
7
>>> 123%10
3
```

I expected that the output of -123%10 to be 3,but the actual output is 7

Comment: That's how it works. Clock analogy: 1 hour after noon (+1pm) is 1:00, 1 hour _before_ noon (-1pm) is 11:00.

Comment: Adding to @tzaman, to solve this you can use `abs(number) % 10`.